# How do I save Repeatable data in my component model?

Tags: custom-component, form-fields-types, model

I've used Repeatable fields in component Options in the past, and am now trying to use that field type in a Form within my component, but the values are not being saved.

Using Firebug, I can see that the data I entered into the modal form is being retained, and (what appears to be) an array of JSON objects is being posted.  That data does get posted (as I can see with Tamper), but this seems to be where thing go awry.

Only the left brace appears to be available from $_POST when I check from the first line of index.php, or using the native $data variable within the model.

With Joomla 3.6, how do I properly post the data from the Repeatable field in my *model* so that it is saved properly in it's entirety to the database in the same way the component Options do from config.xml?

**The Form XML**

```
<field name="chapters" type="repeatable" icon="list" label="Agenda Index" description="Start/Stop times of Agenda items for the meeting Video" >
    <fieldset hidden="true" name="chapters_modal" repeat="true">
        <field name="chapter_start" label="Start Time"  size="15" type="text" />
        <field name="chapter_end"   label="Stop Time"   size="15" type="text" />
        <field name="chapter_name"  label="Name"        size="50" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
</field>
```

**POST data** (via Tamper, before POSTing to Joomla)

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="jform[chapters]"
{
    "chapter_start" : ["01:01:01","03:03:03"]   ,
    "chapter_end"   : ["02:02:02","04:04:04"]   ,
    "chapter_name"  : ["chapter1","Chapter 2"]
}
```

**Model $data**  *(Note only the left brace in the `chapters` element)*

```
public function save($data){
Array
(
    [id] => 9
    [chapters] => {             
    [video_mp4] => 20150226_regular.9.mp4
    [audio_mp3] => 20150226_regular.9.mp3
)
```

**Model Save**

```
$table = $this->getTable();
if ($table->save($data) === true)....
```

**Database column result**   (where the dots are actually blanks)

```
{..............
```

**Form HTML**

```
<form
    id="form-video" 
    action="/index.php?option=com_example&amp;task=video.save&amp;Itemid=185" 
    method="post" 
    class="form-validate form-horizontal" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
>

<div class="controls">
    <button class="open-modal btn" id="jform_chapters_button"><span class="icon-list"></span> Select</button>
    <input 
        name="jform[chapters]" id="jform_chapters" 
        value="{
            "chapter_start":["01:01:00","02:02:02"],
            "chapter_end":["01:01:59","02:02:59"],
            "chapter_name":["Chapter 1","Chapter 2"]
            }" 
        class="form-field-repeatable" 
        data-container="#jform_chapters_container" 
        data-modal-element="#jform_chapters_modal" 
        data-repeatable-element="table tbody tr" 
        data-bt-add="a.add" data-bt-remove="a.remove" 
        data-bt-modal-open="#jform_chapters_button" 
        data-bt-modal-close="button.close-modal" 
        data-bt-modal-save-data="button.save-modal-data" 
        data-maximum="999" 
        data-input="#jform_chapters" 
        type="hidden"
    >
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the original repeatable field is deprecated in favor of the subform field.

I think you need to deal with the data before saving it to the database. What I did for a single text field within a subform field was this in the `postSaveHook` method of the controller:

```
if (!empty($validData['subform']))
{
    $tupel = new stdClass;
    $tupel->id = 0;
    $tupel->refere_id = (int) $validData['id'];

    foreach ($validData['subform'] as $tmp)
    {
        if (empty($tmp['repeatable']))
        {
            continue;
        }

        $tupel->repeatable= $tmp['repeatable'];

        $db->insertObject('#__cross_table_for_repeatable', $tupel);
    }
}
```

`subform` is the name of the subform field, `repeatable` the name of the actual repeated field containing the value.

In my case, I did store it into a n:n table. In your case you may store it as JSON string into the regular table. In that case you would have to convert it from an array to a JSON string before the saving happens. You should be able to do that in the models `validate` method.